# How to handle attempts to hire a programmer for a specific task in a question

Tags: discussion

During Triage, I came across a question that loosely explained an implementation task while promising money and providing contact details. While I am certain that this is *Unsalvageable*, I am struggling as to how exactly I should flag it.

It doesn't really fall under the definition of spam, It is sort of programming related. I don't really want to bother a moderator. So what is the best flag?

Comment: "Blatantly off-topic" flag is a perfect answer here. I'm not sure if "spam" would be accepted or not, but that is definitely not an on-topic question.

Comment: Let me, for the time being, [link the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806011/database-intergration-in-goggle-earth). If I took only the first two sentences it would say "Too broad".

Comment: It doesn't even ask a question.  Set guns a'blazing, anything within reach will do.